# Any good online writing courses?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, poetry

I'm looking for a good online creative writing course to take. I want it to be less than 100 dollars (free would be wonderful), and that can be done for high school credits. I live in Alberta, Canada so I would like the credits to be applicable for my location. Feedback on assignments would also be wonderful, maybe I could email them to the teacher? If anyone knows of a course like this please tell me as I have been looking all over for a course with this criteria. You will truly make my day as I really want to take a good creative writing course.

Comment: It would be nice if you would tell us about whether or not you've researched this. This seems like something you can just look up on google and read some reviews on.

Comment: I have looked at many different websites, I haven't been able to find one with this  this criteria and was wondering if maybe I missed one.

Comment: Citing your research is part of a good question. You need to explain exactly what your problem is and go into detail

Comment: I really liked these two:

Comment: I really liked this one    https://www.virtualhighschool.com/courses/outlines/ewc4u.asp       but found the price tag was a bit high. There was another one I really liked but I can't find it now, if I do I will post a link

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of Massive Open Online Courses (MOOCs)?

Something like this: https://www.coursera.org/learn/craft-of-plot, or the one that appears (I can't post the link as I'm new) if you replace the word 'plot' in that first link with 'setting-and-description'.

That's just a couple  which I stumbled on last week. I think they might be part of a wider series, if you explore the website. They charge a course fee, but there is a free option to 'audit only', which lets you access everything except the assignments. If you're looking to get school credit, maybe you could show the course materials to your English teacher, and agree some suitable assignments he/she is willing to grade for you?

If you'd like something at a good introductory level, I've followed this course, operated by the UK's Open University, and it was worthwhile: https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/start-writing-fiction.

I haven't looked around the internet, and I'm sure you'll find more options if you invest some time in searching. Organisations/websites offering MOOCs include Coursera, FutureLearn, Iversity and edX. There are probably more, too.

Good luck with your writing!